# How to get sum of third relational table column in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have model `Runsheet` run sheet hasMany relation with `Consignment`

```
public function consignments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Admin\Consignment', 'runsheet_id')->orderBy('delivery_address');
}
```

`Consignment` hasMany relation with `Charge`

```
public function charges()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Admin\Charge', 'object_id')->where('model', 'Consignment');
}
```

There is a column in charges table `income` I want to take sum of it through run sheet

```
$run_sheet = Runsheet::find(2)
```

How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

cross three relations would not be possible,it seems you can only do like this.

```php
$run_sheet = Runsheet::with("consignments"=>function($query){
    $query->withSum("charges","income");
})->find(2);
$total_income = $run_sheet->consignments->sum("charges_sum_income");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
$run_sheet = Runsheet::with(['consignments.charges' => function ($query) {
   $query->select('income');
}])->sum('income');
```